# Inserting null numeric values from Python to Snowflake

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to pass null numeric values from Python into Snowflake.

I have created a Snowflake table using

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
col0 int
)
```

in python I am inserting data into Snowflake using

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import snowflake.connector

df = pd.DataFrame({'intVal':[1, np.nan, 3]})

#(cursor is my Snowflake cursor)
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(?)", df.values.tolist())
```

I am getting the error

```
snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 100038 (22018):
Numeric value 'nan' is not recognized
```

What I am hoping to see in my_table is

```
1
NULL
3
```

How should I be entering the data in Python so that I can create a null value in a numeric column of a Snowflake table?

Comment: Why not using **None** instead of Nan. **None** in Python can be considered the equivalent of **NULL**. And of course you can make the column with a DEFAULT NULL meaning when you insert a row, not specifying a value with automatically put NULL.

Comment: If instead I use:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'intVal':[1, None, 3]})`

I get

`TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Comment: After a bit of investigation, I find out that Pandas treats None and NaN as essentially interchangeable for indicating missing or null values. Using **np.nan** should be fine. Your issue seems actually related to a multi-row insert. In multi-row inserts, make sure that the data types of the inserted values are consistent across the rows because the server looks at the data type of the first row as a guide. So casting first value in insert should take care of this like **INSERT INTO foo VALUES (first::int) (second)**, see [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/insert.html)

Comment: I found my problem. I had been looking for and replacing other data errors in my data frame. I was implicitly casting numerical values to strings as part of that data cleansing. The problem was that the entries of interest had been converted to the string 'nan' and not a numerical value - so there was no chance for it to be read as either None or NaN. Oops.